# Watermarking pictures in a sequence before printing them out

Tags: photo-editing, printing, watermark

I have a job coming up and i want to add a number in a sequence as a watermark on photos before printing them. What i mean, is when i upload them i want to add a sequence of numbers on the actual photo and be there when i print them. what program can make that happen? I have tried to search for answer but not really found anything with the exact what i am looking for.

all help and suggestion are appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**To add a visible number to the image:** If you are Mac or Linux, you can use [`bash`](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash%20scripting%20tutorial) scripting with ImageMagick to [construct the desired text](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) and [compose](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) it with your original image. On Windows, you can try PowerShell or batch files instead of `bash`.

**To add a number to metadata:** You can use [`exiftool`](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html) to add any of the following tags: UserComment, XPTitle, XPComment, XPAuthor, XPKeywords, or XPSubject.

Answer (score 1):

I found this Adobe forum post that seems to directly answer your question.  The answer is near the bottom of the post: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2383809